# How to add elements to array in mongodb document if exists empty array otherwise $set in updateMany?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongo-shell

So I have this object

```
{ name: "sunil"
  tags:null
}
{ name: "radha"
  tags:[{k:"max",v:"4"},{k:"min",v:"3"}]
}
```

I want to update both these documents with some new tag objects I want to $set if tags field is null and $push if its not. This is all dummy data but the structure is same for my data as well. I don't see any option to do this in updateMany. Can you please tell me how the can I create a query that can do this?

I tried updateMany with ifNull operator but that is not working its insert $ifNull as it is to the db. I checked the other questions but none of them match my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You need an update query with an aggregation pipeline to add an element by condition:

1. If the `tags` field is `null`, missing, or `undefined`, set an array with the new element in the field.
2. Else, add the element into the `tags` field via `$concatArrays`.

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      tags: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $in: [
              {
                $type: "$tags"
              },
              [
                "null",
                "missing",
                "undefined"
              ]
            ]
          },
          then: [
            {
              k: "new k",
              v: "new v"
            }  // Your new element
          ],
          else: {
            $concatArrays: [
              "$tags",
              [
                {
                  k: "new k",
                  v: "new v"
                } // Your new element
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/En2jpQIEh_x)

Comment: is there any way I can maintain the set characteristic of the tags array.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean *maintain the set characteristic of the tags array*?

Comment: uniqueness in the tags array

Comment: means there should only be one object with one k field value.

Comment: For that case, more like you need implement the filter to determine that the element key to be inserted must not be existed in the `tags` array.